# How to disable sending completion email to embedded signers

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using docusign java SDK in my project for e-signing.
As per my client's requirement I need to disable sending completion email to signers through API call.
Does anyone of you know the **Parameter and Class** that I need to deal with?

Note: I know there is a setting to do this on Docusign Admin page, but I need to disable this feature conditionally from API level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Java SDK look in the `AccountsApi.java` and there's a method there called `updateNotificationDefaults()` which you can use to update the settings programmatically. Note that this is for the entire account, not a specific user.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @InbarGazit. Actually I need to set the value as user specific. So I need to check further. If you find any other parameter please let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: you can do that at the account level or envelope level but AFAIK not at the user level

Comment: one thing you can do is create multiple accounts for the same organization. So, a company has an organization with few accounts, one for HR, one for Legal, one for Finance, etc.

Comment: Hay @InbarGazit, thank you for your suggestion. btw I was able to find a solution for this requirement. I just set value "true" for **suppressEmails** property under _EnvelopeRecipients -> Signer_. Right now, I'm looking for properties to remove senders **First Name & Account Name** from the envelop signing view. If you have any idea to do this. Please let me know.

Comment: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-email-resource-file-v1-1 this should have information about this.
Please do mark this question as answered and ask new questions if it's not the same question. thanks!